# Serilog Appsettings and setting filters

Tags: appsettings, serilog

Using the Serilog.Settings.AppSettings project I am having difficulty setting a filter to exclude certain namespaces from a configured sink.

In code I would do something like this:

```
[...].Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource<MyNameSpace>())
```

However I don't seem able to do it using the app settings.

Is this supported and if so how can I achieve this using configuration?

Thanks

Vincent

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69728057/using-serilog-in-appsettings-json-my-filter-expression-in-the-sublogger-is-not

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the package.

```
Install-Package Serilog.Filters.Expressions
```

Then follow the example here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions and https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/sample/Sample/appsettings.json#L64

```
"Using": ["Serilog.Settings.Configuration"],
"Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "SourceContext = 'MyNameSpace'"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: The Serilog.Filters package has been deprecated in favor of Serilog.Expressions.