# Trouble converting Serilog Configuration to appsettings.json

Tags: logging, configuration, serilog

I have this piece of code on c# which does the job pretty well.
Every log that comes from CSPConsumersLayer get logged on a specific file (ConsumerLog.txt), meanwhile, every other log gets logged on another file (Log.txt).
This is the C# configuration that I want to achieve in appsettings.json

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Console()
.WriteTo.Logger(lg => lg.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource(nameof(CSPConsumersLayer))).WriteTo.File(@"..\Logs\ConsumerLog.txt", LogEventLevel.Information, "{Timestamp:G} [{Level}] {ThreadId} {MachineName} {Message} {Exception}{NewLine}", rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 104857600))
.WriteTo.Logger(lg => lg.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource(nameof(CSPConsumersLayer))).WriteTo.File(@"..\Logs\Log.txt", LogEventLevel.Information, "{Timestamp:G} [{Level}] {User} {IP} {ThreadId} {MachineName} {SourceContext} {RequestId} {Message} {Exception}{NewLine}", rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 104857600))
.CreateLogger();
```

And when I try to convert it on Json-like it won't work

--This is the JSON I have come up with, which doesn't work properly.

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'CSPConsumersLayer')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "../Logs/ConsumerLog.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} [{Level}] {User} {IP} {ThreadId} {MachineName} {SourceContext} {RequestId} {Message} {Exception}{NewLine}",
                  "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
                  "fileSizeLimitBytes": 104857600
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'CSPConsumersLayer')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "../Logs/Log.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} [{Level}] {User} {IP} {ThreadId} {MachineName} {SourceContext} {RequestId} {Message} {Exception}{NewLine}",
                  "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
                  "fileSizeLimitBytes": 104857600
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you please describe a little bit more about " which doesn't work properly". Also try using `"expression": "FromSource(CSPConsumersLayer)" if filtering is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The issue was that I did not include "serilog-extensions-logging" packets, so It couldn't understand the filter expression. Anyways, the expression which best fits my need was "Contains(SourceContext, 'CSPConsumersLayer')".

Comment: ... Sounds like you need to self-answer ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serilog Appsettings and setting filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676962/serilog-appsettings-and-setting-filters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is this simple. If you want to do **filtering** on the **appsettings.json**, you should include a packet called ***'serilog-extensions-logging'***.

Comment: Its great to see good behaviours like interacting with commenters from the off - it's not a given, so its natural to want to give further nudges and votes when you do that!