# Using Serilog in appsettings.json, my filter expression in the sublogger is not working

Tags: serilog, appsettings, serilog-filter

I'm using serilog to write logs to different files based upon namespace. Both files are being created, but nothing is being written to shopify.log. I have two namespaces that I want to include and both of them contain the string "Shopify". I can fully qualify them and pattern match, but that wasn't working either.

I'm using Serilog.Expressions 3.2.0

Any help is appreciated!

```
  "WriteTo": [
          { "Name": "Console" },
          {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "path": "Logs/system.log"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "Logger",
            "Args": {
              "configureLogger": {
                "WriteTo": [
                  {
                    "Name": "File",
                    "Args": {
                      "path": "Logs/shopify.log"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "Filter": [
                  {
                    "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                    "Args": {
                      "expression": "Contains(SourceContext, 'Shopify')"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why 'Contains' was not working, but I changed it to a more query type expression and that is working.

```
"Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "SourceContext like '%shopify%' ci"
            }
          }
        ]
```

The 'ci' indicates that it is case-insensitive, so will match Shopify as well.